# How long can I soak gulab jamun before serving?

Tags: indian-cuisine, syrup

I would like to make some gulab jamun for a party in the afternoon. Because it's a work party, I can't prepare them in the morning and let them soak the recommended few hours. Instead, I need to prepare them the night before.

I have read many recipes and they all recommend a *minimum* soaking time but I have not found one that addresses preparing them ahead of time, or suggests soaking overnight.

Would there by any negative effect if I soaked them in the syrup all night, refrigerated, and then let them warm up to room temperature before serving the next day? Or even multiple days later/indefinitely? I'm not worried about spoilage and I assume any change in texture of the syrup will be reversed as it warms but I'm a little concerned that the texture of the jamuns will change, that they might get too soft or perhaps fall apart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leave your Gulab Jamun in sugar syrup for minimum 30 minutes to maximum as long as you wish.

Before service you can bring Gulab Jamun to room temperature or you can even microwave and serve little warm.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! We ask that you link to your own sites only when it helps answer the question. In this case, the blog post you've linked to doesn't appear to say anything about how long gulab jamun can be soaked, so it's more in the category of unsolicited self-promotion, and I'm going to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Gulab jamun, longer it soaks the better and based on your dough and frying to right texture will help bulge them in size by almost 3/4 of their original size. So try to make your sugar syrup a little runny instead of string consistency.

Comment: Why do you suggest making the sugar syrup a little runny?

Comment: @Air Either you can stop cooking from Syrup getting too thick or add some water if it ends up too thick and continue to dissolve on slow flame.